# For $M$ any finitely generated $R$-module determine $E_R(M)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain with quotient field $K$.

1. For $p$ any prime element of $R$ and $P$ the prime ideal it
   generates, show that $$ E_R\left(R/P\right)  \cong
   K/pR_p \cong K/R_p \cong
   R[p^{-1}]/R $$

I have already done this part.

2. For $M$ any finitely generated $R$-module determine $E_R(M)$.

I assume that I am suppose to use part 1 to do part 2 but I can see how to do that?

Comment: Could you explain what you denote $E_R(M)$?

Comment: Sorry $E_R(M)$ is the injective envelope (also known as injective hull).

Comment: The injective envelope commutes with direct sums, and each f.g. $R$-module is a direct sum of copies of $R$ and $R/P^k$ for prime ideals $P$.

Comment: So $E_R(M)=E_R(R\oplus R/P^k)=E_R(R) \oplus E_R(R/P^k)= Quot(R) \oplus E_R(R/P)^k$ and apply part (a)?